# Trying to deal a deck of cards by using a scanner to specify how many players there are to divide the cards

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a card dealer program and I'm using a scanner to input manually how many number of players there are. But, I'm kind of stuck on how to divide/deal the cards to the specified amount of players.

The result that I'm aiming for is kinda like this

Example: dealing it to 4 players

Spade-2     1stplayer
Queen-Heart 2nd player
Club-5      3rd player
Club-9      4th player
Diamond-7   1st player
Spade-Jack  2nd player
.... and so on until it deals all 52 cards to 4 players

This is the current code that I wrote while looking for tutorials on how to shuffle a deck of cards.

import java.util.Scanner;
public class main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Input how many players there are");
    
    int player = sc.nextInt();
    
    if (player > 0) {
        String[] type = {"S-", "H-", "D-", "C-"} ;
        String[] rank = {"A ", "2 ", "3 ", "4 ", "5 ", "6 ", "7 ", "8 ", "9 ", "10 ", "J ", "Q ", "K "};
        String[] cset = new String[52];
        
    for (int i = 0; i < cset.length; i++) {
        cset[i] = type[i/13] + rank[i%13];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cset.length; i++) {
        int index = (int) (Math.random() * cset.length);
        String temp = cset[i];
        cset[i] = cset[index];
        cset[index] = temp;
    }
    for (String u: cset) {
        System.out.println(u);
}
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please input a correct number of player/s");
    }
}
```

}

Can someone please help me?
Sorry if my explanation is confusing

Comment: Unless you want to write your own shuffling algorithm for some reason, consider putting your cards into an ArrayList, which has a shuffle method that will do the dirty work for you. For dealing, your logic would be something like "while the deck is not empty, loop through the players and hand them the next card in the deck." If you stop to think about the problem a bit more, the solutions will become clear. Get a real deck of cards and go through the motions of dealing if you're having problems conceptualizing. Avoid asking for help until you actually need it because that's not how to learn.

Comment: `Collections.shuffle(arrayList);` is the shuffle @MarsAtomic is referring too by the way, it is in the `Collections` class in case you couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

As noticed by @MarsAtomic and @Nexevis in the comments, you can shuffle an `ArrayList` using static method `Collections.shuffle()`:

Suit.java

```
public enum Suit {
    CLUBS('\u2663'), DIAMONDS('\u2666'), HEARTS('\u2764'), SPADES('\u2660');
    
    private final char symbol;
    
    private Suit(char symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }
    
    public final char getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }
    
}
```

Card.java

```
public static class Card {

    private final Suit suit;

    private final int value;

    private transient final String name;

    public Card(Suit suit, int value) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
        this.name = createName(suit, value);
    }

    public final Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public final int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    private static String createName(Suit suit, int value) {
        char symbol = suit.getSymbol();
        switch(value) {
            case 1:
                return "A" + symbol;
            case 11:
                return "J" + symbol;
            case 12:
                return "Q" + symbol;
            case 13:
                return "K" + symbol;
            default:
                return  Integer.toString(value) + symbol;
        }

    }

}
```

Methods to deal cards:

```
public static List<List<Card>> deal(int players, int playerCards) {
    List<Card> cards = Stream.of(Suit.values())
            .flatMap(suit -> IntStream.range(1, 14)
                    .mapToObj(value -> new Card(suit, value)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    Collections.shuffle(cards);
    
    return IntStream.range(0, players)
            .map(i -> i * playerCards)
            .mapToObj(index -> cards.subList(index, index + playerCards))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static List<List<Card>> dealAll(int players) {
    return deal(players, Math.round(52f / players));
}
```

Then you can do:

```
List<List<Card>> cards = dealAll(4); // or deal(4, 13) if each player has a specific number of cards

cards.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
[5♣, 4♣, 9♣, 7♣, 5❤, 6♠, 3♠, K♦, 4♦, 6♣, Q♦, 9♦, J♦]
[Q♣, 2♦, 9♠, Q❤, 7♦, 10♣, 9❤, 5♠, 2♣, 10❤, 5♦, A❤, 8❤]
[2♠, 8♠, 8♣, 4♠, 10♦, 3♣, 2❤, 3♦, K♣, 7♠, A♣, 3❤, J❤]
[7❤, J♠, 4❤, Q♠, 6♦, 10♠, A♦, K❤, A♠, J♣, 8♦, K♠, 6❤]
```